# make Error running CDT Eclipse on a Mac

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I installed the CDT package via Install Software option in Eclipse, and after that, I installed the Command Line Tools using Xcode on my Mac.  I am running Eclipse Juno on Mountain Lion.

After installing command line tools, I exported the paths with:

export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export CC=/usr/bin/g++

In eclipse, I'm getting this error with auto-generated HelloWorld executable projects and autotools:

```
Error 127 occured while running autoreconf
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.
```

From what I have found, the second has to do with g++, but I'm not really sure what the issue is.

I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought you need `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++`, but maybe that's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've installed the XCode command line tools.
Also you might need to configure the project.

Ideally you invoke aclocal, automake --add-missing and then autoconf.
Then run configure and make. You might need the -i option for autoconf.